# why i can't run app-engine-patch on my gae

Tags: django, google-app-engine, app-engine-patch

this is app-engine-patch http://code.google.com/p/app-engine-patch/

i download it  ,and unzip , but can't running on my google-app-engine launcher

why ?

**updated**

but the patch has app.yaml, and i can't find aep-sample

**updated2**

when i python manage.py runserver

so  can app-engine-patch running on gae launcher ?

Comment: You have asked 278 questions (2.3 per day since you joined this site), and answered six, five of them on your own questions. Please take some time to contribute to the site by answering *other people's* questions.

Comment: You seem to have gotten the app to run now. Congrats. Now help some other people out and answer their questions. Contribute to the site in a way that doesn't immediately benefit you. Asking questions is *sometimes* helpful, but not at the speed or volume or level of carelessness that you seem to be doing it. Google things first. Try things out before asking this community.

Comment: The remote_api handler's path is wrong. Strange as it may seem, once your app is deployed to the Google cloud, it won't be able to load files from your D: drive.

Comment: so  how can i change the  handler's path  ?

Comment: Make it a path relative to your $PYTHON_LIB, like it says in this article: http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/remote_api.html

Answer (score 0):

App Engine Patch isn't an App Engine app, it's a library to use with your app.  If it doesn't have an app.yaml file, it won't be able to be run.

It looks like there's an `aep-sample` app included in the .zip file, try running that.

(response to edit)

The app.yaml file you found references `aep-sample` as the app's name, but the app listed in the launcher says "patch", so something's wrong there.

Have you read the [Getting Started](http://code.google.com/p/app-engine-patch/wiki/GettingStarted) page on the project's site?  Reading the documentation is generally a helpful first step.